# bootstrap-responsive.min.css not found in bootstrap nuget package

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5.1

The bootstrap-responsive.min.css file is not found in the bootstrap nuget package.

Even though CDN is available for the file, I'm using MVC and want to bundle the local file.

Where can this file be found?

Comment: Bootstrap 3 doesn't come with "bootstrap-responsive.min.css". Bootstrap 2.x did

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bootstrap-responsive.min.css` is a Bootstrap v2.x.x-specific file.

It no longer exists in Bootstrap v3.x.x because Bootstrap v3.x.x is responsive by default.